# Can we automate Windows service using karate tool?

Tags: stack-overflow, karate

We are able to automate the API services using karate tool. Is it possible to automate the Windows service using karate tool?

Comment: also see: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-Robot-Windows-Install-Guide